# Is there any example or sample code for the find and filter feature in Cytoscape JS

Tags: cytoscape.js

I saw in cytoscape application we have features like find and filter by keywords and degree. I tried a workaround following the original docs. Here you can see the demo webdemo.intolap.com/cytoscape (view-source for the source code or snippet). The filter works well partially. Example, "apple" will display apple and it's connected nodes (1st level) just what I am looking for.

But the problem I am facing is about resetting the graph and filter again with a 
 different keyword. It seems the filter function does not work after the text box is cleared and then keyed in a different keyword.

I mean when I clear the text box, it resets the graph to original which is correct. I did that using an init() function which reinstates the graph. But then if I search for "Ball" filter does not work. Any help please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to `cy.filter` on a cytoscape instance that no longer exists at that point. That's why it works the first time, but not the second time (after you reinstate the graph, which probably means destroy & create).

You need to make sure you point your filter handlers to the active cytoscape instance.

Answer (score 4):

actually there is a reasonably good explanation in the official docs [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.$), but to be honest, I too struggled with this feature at first:

Basically, you can filter the specific collection you want to search by just inserting a filter query. So if you want to filter all nodes, you can use this:

```
cy.nodes(filterQuery);
```

If you want to filter all elements, just call this:

```
cy.elements(filterQuery);
```

If you want to make it easy, you can use this short version (short for `cy.filter(...)`):

```
cy.$(filterQuery);
```

The filter query itself is not that hard, you can do this (assuming that you have a node with the id "first" or an attribute like nodeColor "#2763c4"):

```
cy.$('[id != "first"]');
cy.$('[id = "first"]');
cy.$('[nodeColor = "#2763c4"]');
cy.$('[weight > 50]');
```

Additionally, you can specify the target collection within your filter query like this:

```
cy.$('node[id != "first"]');
```

Lastly, if you need complex filtering, you can use a function to apply that logic to the filter, for that just do this:

```
cy.$(function(element, i){
  return element.isNode() && element.data('weight') > 50;
});
```

Comment: Hey Stephen,

I tried a workaround foloing the original docs. Here you can see the demo http://webdemo.intolap.com/cytoscape/

Now the problem I am facing is, the filter function does not work after the text box is cleared and then keyed in a different keyword.

Example, Apple will display apple and it's connected nodes (1st level). Bot when I clear the text box, it resets the graph to original, then if I search for Ball it wont work.

Any help.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly (Code Snippet with the relevent parts of your code)

Comment: For the near future, your link may work, but that doesn't have to be the case. That is why I suggest the Code Snippet as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit the question according to these [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidlines, especially the section **Help others reproduce the problem**